# Is Cuda 6 supported with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

Is Cuda 6 supported with Visual Studio 2013?

If not, is there a hack to make the two work with each other?

I see lots of value in upgrading to VS 2013 as it (VC++) better implements the C++11 standard, and to CUDA 6 for its unified memory architecture, and other improvements.

Comment: What is supported for CUDA 6 is spelled out [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).   When I googled, I found stuff [like this](http://www.thomas-zhu.com/test/).

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 [does not fully implement C++11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). What made you think it does?

Comment: @JBentley, thanks for pointing out. I made the correction.

Comment: Who cares about C++11...YOU CAN RESIZE PROPERTY PAGES!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is September 2014, and the production Release of Cuda 6.5 is out, and it works with Visual Studio 2013. No other version of Cuda works with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @thirumal, I have not tested it myself, but I don't see why CUDA 6.5 would not work with Community Edition 2013. Community Edition 2013 is basically the same as VS 2013 Professional. Why dont you try it and let us know? :-)

Answer (score 6):

What is officially supported for CUDA 6 is listed in the cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows pdf document, which is installed with the CUDA 6 toolkit.

VS2013 is not officially supported with CUDA 6.  VS 2013 is officially supported with CUDA 6.5, which can be verified from the corresponding document installed with CUDA 6.5 toolkit.

Comment: it's not an hack..It's just a declaration of using VS2012 compiler inside VS2013 IDE. Which means, you need still VS2012 to compile CUDA6.0 projects.

Then, the right answer is: **No**, VS2013 isn't yet supported by CUDA 6.0.

Comment: Your link links to something completely irrelevant. Please fix.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I've removed all links, and instead replaced it with summary text, which can be verified via a lookup of the documents installed with each toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA 6.5 works with Community Edition 2013 ("new Express", but with more support like MFC and even for small enterprises for free).

Sorry that I could not comment.. I have not 50 reputations -,-    Would kindly thank you all for reputations to support the community here in the future :)