# CUDA - Simple adder program always gives zero

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with a simple CUDA program which just adds two numbers. I run it on a laptop with a Geforce GT320M GPU on Windows 7. I compile this program with `Visual Studio 2013` (I don't know if it means something). The problem is that I always get `0` as a result. I tried to check the given parameters (just return with all the parameters given to the method in an array) and they all seemed to be `0`. I run this program in an other computer (at university) and there it runs completely fine, and returns the correct result. So I think there should be some setting problem, but I am not sure of it.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__global__ void add(int a, int b, int* c)
{
    *c = a + b;

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int c;
    int* dev_c;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int));

    add << <1, 1 >> >(1, 2, dev_c);

    cudaMemcpy(&c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("a + b = %d\n", c);

    cudaFree(dev_c);

    return 0;
}
```

I also run this code snippet that I found somewhere.

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

This isn't returning anything.

Comment: @Pradheep See here please: [_"Is asking reasons for downvote in comments non-constructive?"_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252826/is-asking-reasons-for-downvote-in-comments-non-constructive/252910#252910)

Comment: I'm actually trying to find out what's wrong here. This doesn't look like a trivial issue.

Comment: You may want to read the accepted answer from here. See if that works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524050/simple-adding-of-two-ints-in-cuda-result-always-the-same

Comment: I done the error checking as the above answer said, and I got "invalid device function"

Comment: I think `return` is the problem.

Comment: I tried to remove the return, but I still get the "invalid device function" error. If I call the cudaGetDeviceProperties() then it works fine. I get the device name and everything.

Comment: Are you compiling for the correct architecture? Your card seems to have compute capability 1.1, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I set the compiler in Visual Studio 2013 to compile to 1.1? According to the querystring its 1.2 capable though.

Comment: I'm not a `Visual Studio 2013` user, but in the `2010` version, you do: `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Device` and there you specify, for example, `compute_12,sm_12`.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. The Visual Studio automaticaly setted it to compute_20 and sm_20. I added the 1.2 version there now it works completly fine. Could you write this as an answer so I can mark it and if somebody run into this problem again he/she will find the answer? Or can I mark a comment as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the typical CUDA template to create a new Visual Studio project using CUDA, then you have to take care of correctly setting the compute capability for which to compile, changing the default values if needed. This can be done by setting, for example,

```
compute_12,sm_12
```

in the `CUDA C/C++ Configuration Properties`. In your case, the default compute capability was `2.0`, while your card is of a previous architecture. This was the source of your mis-computations.

P.S. As of September 2014, `CUDA 6.5` is the only version of CUDA supporting `Visual Studio 2013`, see [Is Cuda 6 supported with Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416983/is-cuda-6-supported-with-visual-studio-2013).